# Biopython's ESearch does not give me full IdList

Tags: python, biopython, pubmed

I am trying to search for some articles by using the following code:

```
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term="lung+cancer")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
```

From `record['Count']` I can see there are 293279 results, but when I look at `record['IdList']` it only gives me 20 Id's. Why is that? How do I get all the 293279 records?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default number of records that `Entrez.esearch` returns is 20. This is to prevent overloading NCBI's servers. To get the full list of records, change the `retmax` parameter:

```
>>> from Bio import Entrez
>>> Entrez.email = "A.N.Other@example.com"     # Always tell NCBI who you are
>>> handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term="lung+cancer")
>>> record = Entrez.read(handle)
>>> count = record['Count']
>>> handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term="lung+cancer", retmax=count)
>>> record = Entrez.read(handle)
>>> print len(record['IdList'])
293279
```

The way to download all the records is to use `Entrez.epost`.

From [chapter 9.4 of the BioPython tutorial](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc115):

> EPost uploads a list of UIs for use in subsequent search strategies; see the [EPost help page](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/#chapter4.EPost) for more information. It is available from Biopython through the `Bio.Entrez.epost()` function.
>
> To give an example of when this is useful, suppose you have a long list of IDs you want to download using EFetch (maybe sequences, maybe citations – anything). When you make a request with EFetch your list of IDs, the database etc, are all turned into a long URL sent to the server. If your list of IDs is long, this URL gets long, and long URLs can break (e.g. some proxies don’t cope well).
>
> Instead, you can break this up into two steps, first uploading the list of IDs using EPost (this uses an “HTML post” internally, rather than an “HTML get”, getting round the long URL problem). With the history support, you can then refer to this long list of IDs, and download the associated data with EFetch.
>
> [...] 
>   The returned XML includes two important strings, QueryKey and WebEnv which together define your history session. You would extract these values for use with another Entrez call such as EFetch.

Read [chapter 9.15.:  Searching for and downloading sequences using the history](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc133) to learn how to use `QueryKey` and `WebEnv`

A full working example would then be:

```
from Bio import Entrez
import time

Entrez.email = "A.N.Other@example.com" 
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term="lung+cancer")
record = Entrez.read(handle)

count = int(record['Count'])
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term="lung+cancer", retmax=count)
record = Entrez.read(handle)

id_list = record['IdList']
post_xml = Entrez.epost("pubmed", id=",".join(id_list))
search_results = Entrez.read(post_xml)

webenv = search_results["WebEnv"]
query_key = search_results["QueryKey"] 

try:
    from urllib.error import HTTPError  # for Python 3
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import HTTPError  # for Python 2

batch_size = 200
out_handle = open("lung_cancer.txt", "w")
for start in range(0, count, batch_size):
    end = min(count, start+batch_size)
    print("Going to download record %i to %i" % (start+1, end))
    attempt = 0
    success = False
    while attempt < 3 and not success:
        attempt += 1
        try:
            fetch_handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed",
                                         retstart=start, retmax=batch_size,
                                         webenv=webenv, query_key=query_key)
            success = True
        except HTTPError as err:
            if 500 <= err.code <= 599:
                print("Received error from server %s" % err)
                print("Attempt %i of 3" % attempt)
                time.sleep(15)
            else:
                raise
    data = fetch_handle.read()
    fetch_handle.close()
    out_handle.write(data)
out_handle.close()
```

Comment: By the way, do you happen to know if I want to get descriptions from the GEO database (db=gds), such as this https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sites/GDSbrowser?acc=GDS5648 , can I also use the method you posted?

Comment: Yes, just replace every instance of `"pubmed"` in the script above with `"gds"`.